# spring boot logback refresh

Tags: spring-boot, apache-commons-logging

I know that with config server and refresh endpoint, it is possible to dynamically change the logging level in spring boot application. To get control over the log rotation policy and json encoding for file, I decided to use logback. But this will stop me from dynamically changing the logging level.

```
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>
```

This means that only **info** will be written to console/file. But what if I want to change it to debug/trace during runtime?

**EDIT**
I still dont understand the root level tag. But the logback seems to be taking the log level from application.properties, which basically answers my question.

Comment: use spring-boot actuator

Comment: well.. I thought it is obvious that I use actuator when I mentioned config server and refresh end point

Answer (score 1):

You can change loggig levle using spring-boot-acutuator endpiont.

To check loging level call this `GET` method endpoint:

http://host:port/contextpath/actuator/loggers

To check root level loggers call this `GET` method:

http://host:port/contextpath/actuator/loggers/root

To change root log level call this POST method endpoint:

http://host:port/contextpath/actuator/loggers/root

```
header: content-type: application-json
```

body:

```
{"configuredLevel": "TRACE"}
```

By calling this endpoint u can change root log level.